# Creating multiple selection drop down spinner programmatically Android

Tags: android

I want to create a dropdown dynamically from which i can select multiple items, I have no idea how to do it programmatically, Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: I have some links you can refer to make that type of view follow this links [Multi-Select Drop Down List in Android](https://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/) [Spinner with multiple selection in Android](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html) [How to Customize Spinner in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) Follow This Tutorial It Will help You

Comment: did you check my ans ...if you get it than mark it as accept

Comment: I'd like to add, if you're doing this for a production app (like your job, and not a hobby) consider finding a library instead of coding the thing yourself, otherwise you're gonna lose so much time debugging a view instead of getting actual business logic done

Comment: yes Tufan, i implemented your second link but i can not add listener to that spinner, i want to select multiple as i select i want to get these values in my activity.....

Comment: Christopher Francisco, do you know about any librery like this please share it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620255/creating-multiple-selection-drop-down-spinner-programmatically-android/30620597#30620597